# Not sure where in code to place storageRef.downloadURL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

After updating Firebase to Version 4 and correcting all 200 errors, I am left with 2 warnings which make my app crash.  I looked up this error and tried the resolution with no success:

```
storageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()
```

I must be doing it wrong:

```
func setUserInfo(_ user: User!, usersname: String, email: String, password: String, cell: String, data: Data!) {

    // Create Path for User Image
    let imagePath = "images/riders/\(user.uid)/Profile Pic/userPic.jpg"

    // Create image Reference
    let imageRef = rDataService.Instance.storageRef.child(imagePath)

    // Create Metadata for the image
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    // Save the user Image in the Firebase Storage File
    imageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest.displayName = usersname
            changeRequest.photoURL = metaData?.downloadURL()
            changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

                if error == nil {
                    self.saveUser(user, usersname: usersname, email: email, password: password, cell: cell)

                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            })

        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

The error is happening on this line:

```
changeRequest.photoURL = metaData?.downloadURL()
```

**Edit**

After adjustments, getting warning on this line:

```
if let profilepicMetaData = profilepicMetaData {

error: Value 'profilepicMetaData' was defined but never used; consider  replacing with boolean test
```

App is still crashing:

```
// Save the user profile Image in the Firebase Storage File
    imageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: profilepicMetaData) { (profilepicMetaData, error) in
        if let profilepicMetaData = profilepicMetaData {
            imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                guard let url = url else {
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return
                }
                let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest.displayName = usersname
                changeRequest.photoURL = url

                changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

                if error == nil {
                    self.saveUser(user, usersname: usersname, email: email, password: password, year: year, makeAndModel: makeAndModel, cell: cell, plateNo: plateNo)

                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        })

        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Crash!

[image: crash screen shot]

Comment: The errors went away but my app is still crashing and the only thing it shows is, it crashes and goes to the AppDelegate and the error that appears: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb). But it still doesn't show the users image in the profile page

Comment: @LeoDabus. I created a new user and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the original storage reference object `imageRef` to obtain the download url. (please check the comments through the code):

```
imageRef.putData(data, metadata: profilepicMetaData) {
    // use if let to unwrap the metadata returned to make sure the upload was successful. You can use an underscore to ignore the result
    if let _ = $0 {
        // start the async method downloadURL to fetch the url of the file uploaded
        imageRef.downloadURL {
            // unwrap the URL to make sure it is not nil
            guard let url = $0 else {
                // if the URL is nil unwrap the error, print it 

                if let error = $1 { 
                    // you can present an alert with the error localised description
                    print(error) 
                }
                return
            }
            // your createProfileChangeRequest code  needs to be run after the download url method completes. If you place it after the closure it will be run before the async method finishes.
            let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest.displayName = usersname
            changeRequest.photoURL = url
            changeRequest.commitChanges {
                // unwrap the error and print it
                if let error = $0 {
                    // again you might present an alert with the error
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    // user was updated successfully
                    self.saveUser(user, usersname: usersname, email: email, password: password, year: year, makeAndModel: makeAndModel, cell: cell, plateNo: plateNo)
                }
            }
        }
    } else if let error = $1 {
        // present an alert with the error
        print(error)
    }
}
```